# On which web server does Netbeans run its HTML5 projects?

Tags: html, netbeans, web, webserver, embeddedwebserver

I'm using Netbeans for developing HTML5 projects and I would like to know which embedded web server uses to run this kind of project, though there's no web server mapped in Netbeans yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most embedded common web server is the [Embedded Browser UI - XUL Runner](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38508/embedded-browser) other people can access it trough ip while you develop watching & inspecting it directly into your Netbeans IDE. It's webkit type.